# My pagination doesn't stop, I want to stop when the record is finished

Tags: php

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$rec_limit = 5;

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die(mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('inventray');
/* Get total number of records */
$sql = "SELECT count('id') FROM `issue-pattren`";
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

if(! $retval )
{
  die(mysql_error());
}
$row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM );

$rec_count = $row[0];

if( isset($_GET{'page'} ) )
{
   $page = $_GET{'page'} + 1;

   $offset = $rec_limit * $page ;

}
else
{
   $page = 0;
   $offset = 0;
}

$left_rec = $rec_count - ($page * $rec_limit);


if( $page > 0 )
{
   $last = $page - 2;
   echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$last\">Previous page</a> |";
   echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$page\">Next page</a>";
}
else if( $page == 0 )
{
   echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$page\">Next Page</a>";
}
else if( $left_rec < $rec_limit )
{
   $last = $page - 2;
   echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$last\">Previous Page</a>";
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

This is the code for pagination, and I want to stop my pagination when the record is finished.

When my record is finished the pagination doesn't stop, while I want to stop when the record is finished. So please help me to solve my problem.

I try my best but it didn't work if anyone fix my solution i will be very thankful.

Comment: Just so you know, mysql_ is deprecated. You should really be using PDO. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0):

The principal problem here is your if/else statements, because the last one would never happen, try changing to:

```
if( $left_rec < $rec_limit )
{
   ...
}
else if( $page > 0 )
{
   ...
}
else if( $page == 0 )
{
   ...
}
```

Also as suggested by @Someguy123 you MUST start using MYSQLI or PDO_MYSQL.